# Why gradle's auto-downloading is so much slower than through a web brower?

Tags: android, gradle

When I am Building my helloworld-project in Android Studio.

Because some project dependencies weren't ready(I just install AS a few minutes ago),gradle downloaded them automatically,it downloaded lots of packages.

But the downloading progress got stuck there:

> Download https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-compiler-embeddable/1.9.0/kotlin-compiler-embeddable-1.9.0.jar, took 59 m 5 s 298 ms (58.72 MB)

This 60MB file takes 59 minutes! almost an hour.

Then I copy the web link and download the file in firefox,it only takes a few seconds! This proves that it's not the network's problem.

Then I check my proxy configuration in Android Studio, it's okay and same with my firefox.So what causes such a slow download speed? How to solve it?(I'm trying to solve it by using mirrors, hopefully it works)

I had an idea to find the temporary downloading directory and copy the already downloaded file in it.But where is the temporary directory?

Comment: Could be many different things, but all a bit weird. Could be some traffic shaping disliking non-browser downloads, could be anti-virus going weird, could be slight difference in how proxy settings are applied. What does `curl https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-compiler-embeddable/1.9.0/kotlin-compiler-embeddable-1.9.0.jar` do?

Comment: I've made an update to your question, just minor fixes, if you feel like this changes your question, feel free to change it back. welcome to stack overflow